# How to remove innerHeight and add customer pixels / percentage height?

Tags: jquery, html, animation, html5-canvas

I have been trying to have a custom `height` since few hours but I can't seem to get it working. Is it possible to add custom `height` instead of `window.innerHeight`? Because I don't want the `height` of it to fit the height of the screen.

Here's the code for your inspection:

```
function initHeader() {
    width = window.innerWidth;
    height = window.innerHeight;
    target = {x: 0, y: height};

    largeHeader = document.getElementById('large-header');
    largeHeader.style.height = height+'px';

    canvas = document.getElementById('demo-canvas');
    canvas.width = width;
    canvas.height = height;
    ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');

    // create particles
    circles = [];
    for(var x = 0; x < width*0.5; x++) {
        var c = new Circle();
        circles.push(c);
    }
    animate();
}
```

Here's the jsfiddle of it : [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/x54tn3e0/)

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: I'm getting `Error: requestAnimationFrame is not defined
Line: 86` in your Fiddle

Comment: Hi, thanks.. sorry it's working fine on mine: here's the updated link [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/x54tn3e0/1/) and here's the tutorial demo i'm trying to work on with: [Tutorial](http://tympanus.net/Development/AnimatedHeaderBackgrounds/index2.html)

Comment: i've added jQuery library on it here's the [link](http://jsfiddle.net/x54tn3e0/4/) thanks :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Changing it to

```
height = 100;
```

worked just fine for me on your Fiddle.

So just enter whatever number there you want.

Edit:

To make them fall from the top, change the `Circle` object. In `draw`

```
_this.pos.y -= _this.velocity;
```

to

```
_this.pos.y += _this.velocity;
```

will reverse the direction of the bubbles, and then in `init`

```
_this.pos.y = 0;
```

will set the starting position to the top of the canvas.

Comment: Thanks for that, soo stupid of me I think I was probably adding `px` to it. One quick question, is it possible to have the bubbles come from the top instead it's coming from the bottom now please?

Answer (score 1):

I don't see any reason to doing it not. At the moment I can see two ways:

**1.**

You have just add two additional variables, outside from function (the best option is declare those first and then the function):

```
var myOwnHight = window.innerHeight; //The value can be overwritten
var myOwnWidth = window.innerWidth;  //The value can be overwritten
```

The function it self needs a small modification:

```
function initHeader()
{
  width = myOwnWidth;
  height = myOwnHight;

  ....
}
```

**2:**

An alternative way is to "overwrite" `initHeader()` by coping it and passing values:

```
  //The original
  function initHeader() {
    width = window.innerWidth;
    height = window.innerHeight
   ...
  } 

//The new
function initHeader(myOwnHight, myOwnWidth)
{
  width = myOwnWidth;
  height = myOwnHight;

 ....
}
```

The result is, there exits two different functions with same name. The (modern) browser knows the difference between them and calls the correct function

However you decide, you have to make a small modification in function `initHeader()`.

Comment: That't amazing and very well explained :) made a lot of sense. I'll  go with the first option and apply the modification to the `initHeader` function. One quick question: is it possible to revert the animating bubbles? like they come from the top instead from the bottom? thanks once again :)